# Writing numpy array to rasterio raster file generates empty file

Tags: python, raster, ndvi, numpy, rasterio

I'm using Rasterio to read GeoTIFF from Sentinel 2 and calculating NDVI, but when I try to save as a new TIF file, the file turns to transparent and empty file. What am I missing?

That's the code:

```
class MapService:

    def __init__(self):

        dsRed = rasterio.open('data/bands/B04.TIF')
        bandRed = dsRed.read(1)

        dsNIR = rasterio.open('data/bands/B08.TIF')
        bandNIR = dsNIR.read(1)         

        ndvi = np.zeros(dsRed.shape, dtype=rasterio.float32)

        ndvi = (bandNIR.astype(float)-bandRed.astype(float))/(bandNIR+bandRed)

        kwargs = dsRed.meta
        kwargs.update(
            dtype=rasterio.float32,
            count=1,
            compress='lzw')

        self.ndvi = ndvi
        with rasterio.open('result/example-total.tif', 'w', **kwargs) as dst:
            dst.write(ndvi.astype(rasterio.float32),1)
```

Comment: When you say empty, what exactly do you mean? Is it 0 bytes?

Comment: Nope, but the tiff is transparent. I believe it should be a false color map

Comment: Does the result file really contain only transparent/nodata pixels (check the histogram or some similar statistics)? What happens if you use your code to simply write one of the same files you read in, without any calculations? Can you share the input files?